# Why does Avast and other antivirus' detect gpu miners as viruses?

Tags: cgminer, virus

For example I was downloading [the latest cgminer](http://ck.kolivas.org/apps/cgminer/3.5/) and Avast blocked the download saying it was a virus. Is this true or is it a false positive? I've had other antimalware (I think Malwarebytes) detect cgminer as a virus.

Comment: Also true for CPU miners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is probably because hackers install these miners on peoples computers without their knowledge or make a botnet of miners.

Solution to this is placing your miner to ignore-list or get another antivirus like Avira, Avg, or just switch to linux and no need for antivirus anymore.

Comment: Is Eset good?..

Answer (score 0):

Antivirus and Windows defender will block most of the Miner programs and wallet files. They are false positive and you can add exception to it. Before you do it make sure you've downloaded the program from reliable resource.
Here is a interesting guide which I found on this

https://coinguides.org/miner-detected-virus/